# Can I define a cross container TabIndex order in XAML (or code-beside)

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, .net-3.5, layout

```
Control.TabIndex
```

Only allows me to overide the Tab order of controls in a given container.

Is there a way to specify this across all the controls in, for example a UserControl, regardless of the contains used to arrange the controls.

Cheers,

Jan

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that there is a particularly good way of doing what you are asking, but check out [Changing WPF focus in code](http://www.julmar.com/blog/mark/PermaLink,guid,6e4769e5-a0b3-47b2-a142-6dfefd0c028e.aspx).

That uses `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation` to set how the various containers take and give up the Focus on tabbing, and also sets the `TabIndex` properties for each control. Look at the example code with the `TabNavigation` set to "Continue".

If your tabbing problems are simple, you should be able to find a solution here, if they are complex of need to be generalised, then it might take some more work.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of focus handling is horrible in WPF. The best approch is to make a lot of controls not accept focus with Focusable="False".

The TabNavigation answer would solve the tab key however the arrow keys will not work like you want.